# Port not accessible

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, remote-desktop, port, port-forwarding

Am using AWS windows EC2 instance. I set the inbound rules in the machine to open all ports for public access. I installed IIS, and XAMPP in 8080 port.

Now I could use `123.234.345.456` to open IIS and
`123.234.345.456:8080` to open XAMPP. No problems so far.

Now I installed Telerik Sitefinity project manager. It created a dynamic port `14356` but when I use `123.234.345.456:14356` it says site can't be reached. I tried reinstalling application and reusing the port with XAMPP and all works. But whatever port that Sitefinity Project Manager uses (it is dynamic per start) it never works.

But in the RDP I can access all these ports like

```
localhost
localhost:8080
localhost:14356 //Or any port created by Sitefinity
```

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -na | grep 14356` (or the port the APP is running)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I suspect your application is listening only on localhost (127.0.0.1) and this why it is not accessible externally. You can find it out yourself by running:

`netstat -na | grep 14356`

In that case you will need to change the applications configuration so that it listens to all or on the ip address reachable externally (0.0.0.0:14356 or 123.234.345.456:14356)

It turns out that you are running a trial version and it is meant to be run only on localhost.

> Use a free trial version for any of the editions.
>
> Sitefinity trial versions are for evaluation purposes only. You can run a trial only on local host. After the trial expires, the website redirects to the
> Sitefinity Activate a license page.

Ref: http://docs.sitefinity.com/create-projects

Comment: This is my netstat extract: `[::1]:80`, `[::1]:8080`, `127.0.0.1:14356`

Comment: @Thamizhan, As I have suspected, the application is listening only on local ip (127.0.0.1:14356). Are you running a trial version?

Comment: Yes, it (sitefinity) is trial version. So how can I make 127.0.0.1 IP visible?

Comment: I guess, you cant. The trial version is meant to be run only on localhost. http://docs.sitefinity.com/create-projects

Comment: oh bad! But isn't there any option for 127.0.0.1 IP visibility?